# Ubuntu 18.04 desktop icon overlapping?

Tags: 18.04, icons, .desktop, desktop-icons

I'm getting desktop icons & files overlapping issue on ubuntu 18.04 latest release. I think it's bug.

[image: Desktop image]

**Is there any to solve this problem?**